# Google drive keeps deleted files/folders (as seen in webapp)

Tags: google-drive

So. I've reorganized directory structure in gdrive folder. On local PC everything is good. But in web application, old directory structure remains with overlapped new directory structure (tho, files that were moved to other, new, folders, are left where they were)

Say, I had folder named `1`, I created folder `2` inside it and moved all files from `1` to it. also added some new files in `1` and `2`. Now directory `2` appeared, but files from `1` are not moved. New files are added to `1` and `2`. Also i removed some files completely, but they are still where they were in webapp.

Dropbox handles this as expected.

UPDATE:
At first, question was, is it standard behavior. But now, when it've become obvious, that this behavior is abnormal, question is: how to fix it.

Comment: So what’s your question?

Comment: At first, question was, is it standard behavior. But now, when it've become obvious, that this behavior is abnormal, question is: how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One reason this could happen is if Google Drive sync is stuck or not even running on your computer.

Check to see if the Drive Sync icon is visible in the system tray on Windows, or the menu bar on Mac, or wherever it appears on Linux. If not, start it up.

If it is visible, check if it shows sync errors. Often the easy way to fix that is to make it exit, then start it up again. Or reboot.

**Edit:** If this is happening while GDrive says "Sync complete", then something's wrong.

Have you exceeded your GDrive storage limit? (See the summary in the lower left of the Google Drive web page, or click its Gear icon then open its Settings window.)

Otherwise, it sounds like a bug to report. Click the Gear icon > Help > Send Feedback.

Comment: Yeah, I've done this all already, but no luck still.

Comment: Does it say "Sync complete"? BTW, Drive used to be able to tag a file with multiple labels, which looks like the file is "in" multiple "folders". I think this capability is now mostly hidden.

Comment: Yeah, it says "sync complete". That's why I'm here, actually: I think I've explored every "standard" method to diagnoze it and fix it.

Comment: Puzzling. I'm unable to reproduce this. I added two more hypotheses above.

Comment: answer accepted because it was some straight up glitch and it fixed itself after some time. all my research has lead to nothing. i must to be accustomed already to the fact google drive is glitchy..